# How do I get current map rotation value in MapBox?

Tags: mapbox

I have custom drawn icons that I am rendering on top of a MapBox instance at angles that correspond to their direction of travel, but things start to look at little weird when you right-click and rotate the map.

The icons continue to render at the same angle, while the *actual* direction is now altered by the map rotation. I've got planes flying sideways...

How do I get the map rotation value from the MapBox instance, so I can automatically adjust the rotation of my icons to account for this?

Comment: [HomerPlata](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/56116/homerplata), can you please show us some part of your code which defines those images parameters? Have you checked this article [Add custom icons with Markers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/)?

Comment: The code that renders the icons is totally custom and is not relevant to the discussion, I just need a degree rotation value which I can use to alter the already-working icon rendering code. Do you know of a function for getting the rotation value from the MapBox instance?

Comment: You may try these functions: `"icon-rotation-alignment": "map"` or `"icon-rotate": "{ORIENTATION}"`, chech this out [https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/8303](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/8303)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to solve it. I just opened the developer console in my browser, typed *map.* and looked down the list of available functions, whereupon I discovered:

> map.getBearing();

Comment: It's documented at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/ along with the rotate events to know when a rotation has taken place.